# Send an email to a contact when a lead is converted

Tags: workflow, contact, lead-conversion, email-alert

I'm trying to send an automated email to the contact created when a lead is converted. I'm trying to use workflow but with no succes

[image: Image of workflow]

Here's the image of the workflow I created but with no success. I can use apex but would prefer a simpler solution for what seems an easy task. Has anybody done something like this? Why is this workflow not working correctly?

Comment: Why not use process builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this workflow action on the `Lead` object itself, checking `isConverted` as `true` and send the email.

Comment: Could this be done with a workflow rule or only an apex trigger would work?

Comment: workflow itself

Comment: Perfect I knew it had to be something easy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

its' easy you can use workflow or trigger
but my favorite process builder is so easy,you can use that
isConverted as true and send the email.